# How to install SSL on node.js server

Tags: node.js, web, web-developer-toolbar

I bought SSL Cert from hostgator.in and they have installed it in my linux server. But how do I enable it using node.js code?

Comment: Nodejs has https module, try it. Here is some basic https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-use-ssltls-with-node-js/

Answer (score 0):

After reading Sangs link I would also recommend looking trough the official Nodejs docs for how to implement TSL/SSL.

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/tls.html#tls_tls_ssl_concepts